# Reinstall Office 2011 without dmg?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I currently run Lion with Office 2011 and need to re-install Lion after wiping out my HD. I however no longer have the DVD with which I installed Office. How shall I go about re-installing it again having no access to the DVD anymore?

Comment: Do you have a working backup?

Comment: Yes, on Time Machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [download the Office 2011 Trial](https://www.microsoft.com/mac/trial) and enter your product key in the Setup Assistant. If you also lost your product key, you'll probably need to [contact Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/contactus). You can find info about replacing your DVD at this [Microsoft Support page](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;%5Bln%5D;326246).

Comment: I might be wrong, but ISTR that product keys for DVD versions don't work with the download version. I think this is still the first thing to try, but don't be surprised if it doesn't work. (This is why I immediately make a disk image of all my software DVDs, in case I lose the physical disk.) You also might try backing up your /Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.licensing.plist file and then restore it after you reinstall (not sure that will work either, but it's an idea).

Comment: I have definitely used @joelseph's solution with Microsoft Office 2008. I had it installed initially, ran into problems, etc., that required uninstalling it. I did not have the original disc, though, so I downloaded the trial .dmg from Microsoft, installed, entered my product key, and it worked perfectly. This behavior might have changed with 2011 but I have not had to re-install 2011 so I can't say for sure. It's worth a go, though, as the worst-case scenario is that you simply uninstall the trial software if it's a no-go.

Comment: @TJLuoma According to the 4th question of the [Trial FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/faq/trial), you can "convert" the trial to the full product using a product key that was purchased either online or from a boxed version. I do agree, though, that making a disk image of your software DVDs is a very good idea (installing from disk images is usually quite a bit faster than from DVDs, too).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a working backup on Time Machine, you can reinstall Lion, then run **Migration Assistant**, restoring both user accounts and applications from the Time Machine drive.[image]

For me, this worked to reinstall Microsoft Office without resorting to the physical media and without having to download or re-enter product keys.

Answer (score 1):

The trial software download is no longer on Microsoft's page above -- just Office 365. However, I was able to get a download link in less than one minute using the LiveChat feature to contact an agent. She gave me a link to a page that asked for my product key and that subsequently gave me a download link.

Comment: good support ...